# Adapter pattern in C#

Tags: c#, design-patterns, adapter

I'm wondering whether I understand this pattern correctly. Let's assume that we have interface incompatibility.
Function Printer() from 3rd party dll, requires IHPPrinter, but our object does not implement this interfece... So finally we have got to implement this interface and return our implementation of method, like in code below? :)
The second question is, if we don't provide implementation for method DocumentsInQueue, exeception will be thrown. Is some possibility to prevent calling this method?

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        EpsonPrinter _epsonPrinter = new EpsonPrinter();
        Printer(_epsonPrinter);
        Console.ReadKey();
    }


    public static void Printer(IHPPrinter hpPrinter)
    {
        hpPrinter.PrintDocument();
    }

    public interface IHPPrinter
    {
        void PrintDocument();
        int DocumentsInQueue();
    }
    public interface IEpsonPrinter
    {
        void Print();
    }

    public class EpsonPrinter : IEpsonPrinter, IHPPrinter
    {
        public int DocumentsInQueue()
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public void Print()
        {
            this.PrintDocument();
        }

        public void PrintDocument()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Printing from Epson printer...");
        }


    }
}
```

Comment: You are not implementing the Adapter pattern, essentially you are implementing two interfaces on the same class.

Answer (score 2):

The code you provided is not an example of the Adapter Pattern.

An adapter for your example would be its own class, probably something like `EpsonPrinterToHpPrinterAdapter`. It would implement `IHPPrinter` and take an instance of an `IEpsonPrinter` implementation as an argument to its constructor.

You would then pass an instance of `EpsonPrinterToHpPrinterAdapter` to the method that expects `IHPPrinter`. The adapter class would then translate all calls from `IHPPrinter` methods to calls to the reference of the `IEpsonPrinter` from the constructor.

Thr primary goal of the Adapter pattern is to have a class to makes class `B` act like class `A` by translating, as best as possible the behavior from one to the other.  You can't prevent a member from being called, you have to provide some kind of special implementation of it that will work for the class you are adapting.

In your specific example, it would be fairly trivial to pass the call of `PrintDocument` to `Print` directly, but the call to `DocumentsInQueue` is more difficult, since there is no matching member on `IEpsonPrinter`.  You might have to track and return the count separately, incrementing an internal counter every time `PrintDocument` is called, and decrementing it when it finishes.

This type of pattern becomes very important when you don't controll all parts of those code.  If the `EpsonPrinter` and the `Printer` classes were both defined in 3rd party libraries that you can't modify, you would use this pattern to connect them together.

I've taken your example and made the changes needed to use an Adapter pattern:

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            EpsonPrinter epsonPrinter = new EpsonPrinter();
            EpsonPrinterToHPPrinterAdapter adapter = new EpsonPrinterToHPPrinterAdapter(epsonPrinter);
            Printer(adapter);
            Console.ReadKey();
        }


        public static void Printer(IHPPrinter hpPrinter)
        {
            hpPrinter.PrintDocument();
        }

        public interface IHPPrinter
        {
            void PrintDocument();
            int DocumentsInQueue();
        }
        public interface IEpsonPrinter
        {
            void Print();
        }

        public class EpsonPrinterToHPPrinterAdapter :  IHPPrinter
        {

            public EpsonPrinterToHPPrinterAdapter(IEpsonPrinter epsonPrinter)
            {
                EpsonPrinter = epsonPrinter;
                _queueCount = 0;
            }

            private int _queueCount;

            public IEpsonPrinter EpsonPrinter { get; }

            public void PrintDocument()
            {
                _queueCount++;
                EpsonPrinter.Print();
                _queueCount--;
            }

            public int DocumentsInQueue()
            {
                return _queueCount;
            }
        }

        public class EpsonPrinter : IEpsonPrinter
        {
            public void Print()
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Printing from Epson printer...");
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Great, I understood your approach, is much better then my code.

Comment: But I think i does it mean, that my code isn't correct implementation of this pattern. What do you think?

Comment: Correct, your code is not using the adapter pattern.  I don't think there is a specific name for what you made.

Comment: I included your example, modified to show the adapter pattern.

Comment: I'd just like to add that it would be perfectly valid to have a class that implements both `IEpsonPrinter` and `IHPPrinter` interfaces.  It may even be a good design for some situations; it just isn't the Adapter pattern.